# what is the difference between a double major and dual specialisations in regards to a masters degree?

Tags: major

I'm reviewing a masters programme in counselling and consulting psychology, but am confused as to whether this is a dual specialisation or double major.

What are there criteria for both?

Points to note: the time frame is 30 months (2.5 years)

Comment: I would advise you to ask them. Typically masters do not have majors like an undergraduate degree so you have a focus. My focus was on GIS in a Geography MA, it states this on my transcript. I could have a dual focus named on my diploma. GIS and Remote Sensing in Geography  MS but I do not.

Comment: Specifying the region of the place where you are looking will also help, as these sorts of terminology issues tend to have a strong language/country element. In the US for instance there is no clear meaning difference between the terms that is consistent between University's/departments, so there would be no way at all to know without additional information from them directly.